# Navigate is not defined in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have some question about my code, I want to navigate to the createMeetup screen by using following code, but it has error.

[image]

Error like this:

[image]

and this is my navigator:

[image]

Need help, many thanks!

Comment: Copy and paste your code in the question instead of taking a screenshot.

Answer (score 6):

If you are searching for this,Remember Now we have hooks from navigation.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const NextPageButton = ()=>{
  //use navigation hook shown as below
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title="Naigate to next page"
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate('MyNextPage'); 
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default NextPageButton
```

'MyNextPage' is referring to 'name' prop in your navigation routes.
visit [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is...`navigate` is not defined.

Add in `navigation` prop:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation: { navigate } }) => ({
  title: ...
  ...
})
```

Comment: thanks! but has other error: Invariant Violation: objects are not valid as a react child (found: object with keys {title, headerTitleStyle, headerStyle, headerRight}), how to solve this?

Comment: Updated code, remove `header` and move the `({` to the `navigationOptions` instead.

Comment: Hi riwu, I am a new learner for react native, if possible, could you briefly explain the difference between these three codes for me? (the one I originally wrote, the first answer you gave and the right one) Many thanks!

Comment: The one you wrote did not define `navigate`. The react-navigation API allows `navigationOptions` (not `header`) to be defined as a function, which will be invoked with the navigation prop, so we make use of that to get the `navigate` prop to use in the `onPress` function.

Comment: @biubiubiubiubiu Please mark it as answer if it's resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the navigation to your function's prop like this:

```
function something (**{navigation}**){
    // Function body
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify which function you mean by `something`?  The OP does not seem to be writing a functional component, and has not explicitlly defined any `render` method.  Once they somehow receive the `navigation` parameter, do they need to change their `navigate` call to `navigation.navigate`?

Comment: by something I meant the functions name and yes when you pass navigation,you should use navigation.navigate() . inside you should give the name of the screen chosen when you were adding it to the <stack.navigator>

Comment: complete guide is here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating